# Updating Gemfile.lock without installing gems

Tags: ruby, bundler, gemfile.lock

Is there a way to force an update of the `Gemfile.lock` without installing the gems that have changed?

Comment: Why do you want / have to do that?

Comment: Maybe there's a better way, what exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: I am deploying to an external service which requires some specific versions of some gems which won't install on my system. The only way to make the service work is to have a valid Gemfile.lock with the required versions. I could go in and do it manually in the Gemfile.lock, but I would prefere to be able to update it "properly" using bundler.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Bundler updates gems by installing them. You could either log in to the external service and run `bundle update` there or set up a virtual machine matching your external service locally.

Comment: @Stefan I am afraid that is not possible. The service, Heroku, is not easily virtualised. It works by looking at a git repo which you push to the service, and it sort of bootstraps from there.

Comment: You should submit a support ticket. From Heroku's [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gems): *"Almost any gem - even those with native dependencies - can be installed using Bundler. If there’s a specific gem that won’t install on Heroku, please [submit a support ticket](https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new)."*

Comment: Well, in my case, Rmagick is a gem that is  outside of "almost any". They specify that you need version 2.12.0, but that won't install on my machine, thus, I would like to have a valid Gemfile.lock that I can push to Heroku, even though it won't install on my machine. I have got this working by manually changing the Gemfile.lock, but it is not a preferred solution.

Comment: Are you sure? https://github.com/andyw8/rmagick-heroku-demo specifies [rmagick (2.13.2)](https://github.com/andyw8/rmagick-heroku-demo/blob/master/Gemfile.lock#L7) and it seems to be running fine.

Comment: Strange.. I got an error when I ran `git push heroku master` saying "... You have added to the Gemfile:
       * rmagick (= 2.12.0)

       You have deleted from the Gemfile:
       * rmagick ..."

Anyway, I think it would be nice to be able to generate the Gemfile.lock without needing to install everything, though I see that it might require to download all the source to see what depends on what.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Run `bundle lock --update`.**

I found an answer in a blog post by Chris Blunt: [“Rails on Docker: Quickly Create or Update Your Gemfile.lock”](https://www.chrisblunt.com/rails-on-docker-quickly-create-or-update-your-gemfile-lock/):

> Today, I discovered a way to save the hours wasted downloading gems: bundler’s **lock** command.
>
> This gem of a command resolves your app’s dependencies and writes out the appropriate `Gemfile.lock` – without installing any of the gems themselves.

According to the changelog, this command was added in [Bundler 1.10.0.pre](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1100pre-2015-05-03), released about eight months after this question was asked.

Comment: More concretely, I had to run `bundle lock --update`.

Comment: `bundle lock` without `--update` will add missing gems to the `Gemfile.lock` without doing possibly harmful updates.

Comment: This is inaccurate. The `--update` flag *will* update the gems. Which is precisely what the question requests **not** to do. 

Answer (score 8):

Instead of

```
bundle install
```

do the following:

```
bundle lock
```

This will just update the `Gemfile.lock`, but not attempt to install the files locally.

If you want to prepare a `Gemfile.lock` for a remote or deployment platform you must add it using

```
bundle lock --add-platform ...
```

Latest docs at https://bundler.io/v1.16/man/bundle-lock.1.html

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: This is still supported by the current (2.4) version but has been deprecated in favour of the [`lock` command](https://bundler.io/v2.4/man/bundle-lock.1.html).

Force your specific requirement using:

```
bundle inject rmagick "=1.7.1"
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I keep getting "you specified rmagick(_some_version) and rmagick (injected_version)"

Comment: In the Gemfile, move your (dev) version to the development group and leave Heroku's in the main section (make sure you deploy to Heroku --without development).

Comment: As of at least 2023, the `help` says that `bundle inject` is outdated and should no longer be used.